Cohomology with coefficients in the group ring $\mathbb{Z}G$ from the cohomology in $\mathbb{Z}$
I've computed, for an infinite group $G$, the cohomology ring $H^\ast(G,\mathbb{Z})$. The cohomology groups $H^i(G,\mathbb{Z})$ are free abelian and the $H^\ast(G,\mathbb{Z})$ is generated by the one-dimensional classes. Knowing this information, is there a natural/canonical way to compute the groups $H^i(G,\mathbb{Z}G)$? In fact, it would be enough to know if each $H^i(G,\mathbb{Z}G)$ is trivial or not.
I've seen that it is possible to write $H^i(G,\mathbb{Z}G)$ as $Tor_i^{\mathbb{Z}G}(\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z}G)$ but I don't know if this is anyway easier to compute.

In general, no. But maybe in a particular case you are considering one can get something.

The cohomology groups $H^i(G,\mathbb{Z})$ are free abelian and the $H^\ast(G,\mathbb{Z})$ is generated by the one-dimensional classes, maybe it helps. Although, good to know there is no general way, thanks!

It will be not nearly enough, even for groups of small cohomological dimension.

Okay, thank you!
